# Change EDIT to UNDO

Tags: word-ladder

On your computer right now, you can probably click on the "Edit" menu; and one of the first options will be "Undo".  These are closely associated words.  But how close are they in a word ladder?

**Challenge:**  Change EDIT to UNDO by changing one letter at a time.  Each intermediate word must be a valid word in (modern) English.

The accepted answer will be:

1. The shortest chain of words that uses only uncapitalized words (i.e., no proper nouns) in [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/) (and their pluralizations, tenses, etc.)
2. If no such answer is found, the shortest chain of words including proper nouns from the Merriam-Webster Dictionary.
3. If no such answer is found, the shortest chain of words using any other modern English dictionary, including proper nouns.

Acronyms are not allowed.  I know of a solution satisfying criterion #1, which uses one relatively obscure word.

EDIT: somehow I forgot that there were words other than nouns.  My intent was only to prohibit proper nouns in Criterion #1, not to prohibit any words other than nouns.

Comment: Why does the chain require nouns when the two words in question are ostensibly not nouns?

Comment: Those are the intermediate words.

Comment: @Christian:  Sorry, that was a misstatement on my part.  My intent was to prohibit proper nouns for criterion #1.  I've edited the statement accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: These are all in Merriam-Webster and the steps are all nouns (one an abbreviation).

> EDIT [EPIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epit) [SPIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spit) [SNIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snit) [UNIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unit) [UNIO](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unio) UNDO
>  6 steps.

These are all in Merriam-Webster but they are not all nouns (proper or improper).

> EDIT [EMIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emit) [SMIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smit) [SNIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snit) [UNIT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unit) [UNIO](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unio) UNDO
>  6 steps.

Comment: Wow! I literally thought of that right before you posted it! The noun rule makes it a lot harder.

Comment: I wonder whether "improper nouns" was an error and "words that are not proper nouns" was intended.

Comment: What improper noun can you get from edit even (if it was intended)?

Comment: @Duck Perhaps Exit?

Comment: Hmm.. will look into that.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan:  Yes, that was the intent.  I've corrected the puzzle accordingly.